# Bash script loop analysis

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

What do I have to do to this bash script to have it repeat "Enter a student name to get their score:" and stop when the user enters blank space when asked to enter a name again? Currently it takes in the name and returns the score only once. I am trying to use a while loop to repeat the process "while continue=0". I know its something simple I am just stuck.

Here is my code

```
continue=0
while [[ continue -eq 0 ]]; do
            echo " "                                                                                                                
            echo "Enter a student's name to get their score: "
            read sName
            echo "Searching for $sName's score"
            length=${#names[@]}
            start=0
            end=$((length -1))
            while [[ $start -le $end ]]; do
                    mid=$((start + ((end - start)/2)))
                    midName=${names[mid]}
            if [[ $midName > $sName ]]; then
                    end=$((end-mid-1))
            elif [[ $midName < $sName ]]; then
                    start=$((mid+1))
            else
                    echo "${scores[$mid]}"
                    exit 0
            fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Where do you change `$continue`?

Comment: `exit 0` will exit the entire script. Maybe you want `break` instead

Comment: Without evaluating the correctness of the rest of the original code, I believe one issue is the missing `$` on `$continue` in the `while` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example of how to achieve what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
   echo "Enter a student's name to get their score: "
   read name

   if [[ -z $name ]]
   then
      break
   fi

   # got name, continue processing

done
```